# How to start a program always on second monitor

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, xfce, monitor, window-manager

I tried to Google and to browse/search the questions but with no luck.

I have Xubuntu 12.10 installed and extended desktop is working great (Intel display driver). The problem is that I want to start `feh` slideshow on startup on the second monitor. Because of extended desktop I only have `DISPLAY=:0` and thus it is not possible to use `DISPLAY=:1` or `:0.1`.

I have a startup script which runs feh in startup and it does start on second monitor because it seems that the mouse pointer is about in the middle of the desktop. But the script runs feh over and over again to assure that feh gets refreshed file list in case there are new images in the directory (a shared dropbox folder). So if the cursor happens to be on main monitor (which it obviously is when using the computer) feh starts on it and I have to move mouse pointer to second monitor and kill feh.

So I was thinking if I would use two screens and define each monitor on its own screen but because of XFCE there is no `xorg.conf` to configure two screens. I understand that it is though possible to use `xorg.conf` but how to configure it? I tried google-ing it also but with no luck again :(

So either I need a way to start feh always in the second monitor or a way to have feh understand there are new images in the directory :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar issue and used the geometry to determine which monitor should display the image when using additional monitors in extended mode.  The issue is that the system sees the monitors as a single display with a single geomerty.  Using the xy offset you can dictate where the image displays

i.e.  I have two monitors A-1920x1080  and B-1680x1050

To display on the B monitor, I use the following

```
feh --recursive --randomize --auto-zoom --geometry 1680x1050+1920+0  --slideshow-delay 5 -B black --action "gvfs-trash '%f'" ~/Pictures
```